# I don't post code, but the editor requires me to format as code

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, code-formatting, quality-filter

Question in question: [The Facebook app I create doesn't present in my profile setting. How to find User ID for Facebook App ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66326734/3416774)

While I'm not sure which part the checker thinks it as code, I suspect the quote below is the victim:

[image]

Comment: I just edited your question to what's shown in the screenshot and it accepted it just fine. I'm not sure if this is a limitation specifically for the OP or if it has something to do with reputation. Can you still reproduce this after my edit?

Comment: There should be a space between `>` and the number.